# How to find the cause of defect in a process

Tags: r, feature-selection

Suppose a product A undergoes a certain process. This product A is produced at a rate of 8000 per month and out of those in 75 cases defects are generated. In the data set, I have rows corresponding to each product and in the columns I have a about 500 variables corresponding to different process parameters. So, how should I go about finding the variables which are the reasons for the defects in final product? I mean how should I approach this type of problem?

Comment: This is a difficult problem. How much data do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Given your relatively small number of actual defects, one option would be to consider **anomaly detection**.  This is obviously providing a direction rather than any practical advice, but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) has some basic information.